# Python, CX freeze Error, when I try to launch my exe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter, cx-freeze

hello

I try to learn Python ...
I did by myself a little software for read data from XLSX, **every things runs good when I launch by the "normal way** / python way " (ctrl + B in sublime text). 
 ... BUT ...
When I compil it to get my ".exe" with "cx.freeze" and when launch my .exe, I get this error window :

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2GVw.png)

I tryed with the library asked I updated all my library but nothing

here the begin and the end of my code with the library installed by PIP:

```
# c-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Bibliotheques
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openpyxl
import xlrd
import mpl_toolkits
import sys
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.filedialog import *  # askopenfilename
from functools import partial
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class MyApp(Tk):  # --- Class.N°1 --- #
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp()
```

here the CX.freeze scrypt I used :

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os.path

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

base = "Win32GUI" #pour appli graphique ss windows
#base = "console" #pour appli console

options = {
   'build_exe': {
       'include_files':[
           os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
           os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
       ],
   },
}

# On appelle la fonction setup
setup(name = "GraphEditor",
   options = options,
   version = "V1.1.2",
   author = "Scorn",
   description = "Reading and editing trends from 2D table",
   executables = [Executable("GraphEditor.py",base=base, icon="xln.ico")]
)
```

So my question is : why I have this error, and how I can solve it ?

thx you for your time and your answer  :)

Answer (score 1):

I found that CXFreeze had not worked well in many cases. So I prefer to use **Nuitka** as an alternative. It's quite straightforward to use.

`nuitka --file-reference-choice=runtime --recurse-to=[some_module] main.py`

I used Nuitka to freeze a very big Python app (integrated web server using NumPy and OpenGL). Some reports say there's some problem when compiling NumPy. But I think Pandas will be fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I used the very very good: **Auto PY to EXE**   https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/ .

I downgrade my Python to V 3.7

Take care to clean your library because for example: I had 2 times Tkinter, downloaded one time by PIP and already inside the standard library.